# NULL values in a string to date conversion

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table with the following data:

```
logs.ip               logs.fecha                logs.metodo
66.249.93.79          19/Nov/2018:03:46:33      GET
```

All data columns are string and I want to convert logs.fecha into date with the following format: YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

I try the following query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fecha, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) FROM logs
```

Results of the query are NULL in all rows.

How can I make the conversion string to date for all rows? I know I must use ALTER TABLE but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get `null` is because the format of the input string is different from the input passed to `unix_timestamp`. The second argument to `unix_timestamp` should specify the string format of the first argument. In `from_unixtime` you can specify the output format desired. If nothing is specified, a valid input to `from_unixtime` returns an output in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

The error can be fixed as below.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(fecha,'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The query works but it doesn't appear hour. I fixed it using substring.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to tell Oracle the date format you are reading with TO_DATE.
Try:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(fecha,'DD/MON/YYYY:HH:MI:SS') FROM logs
```

Comment: this is not `oracle`. please review the tags before answering.